# Lisp: same mathematical function evaluates to different values at different time?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to compute a polynomial like this --

f(x) = x^4 - 2.274x^3 + 1.8x^2 - 0.576x + 1.0

with this lisp function --

```
(defun polynomial (x)
  (+ (+ (+ (+ (expt x 4) (* -2.274 * (expt x 3)))
       (* 1.8 (* x x))) (* -0.576 x)) 0.1))
```

when I call (polynomial 0.5) the result is different at different evaluations, like this --

```
CL-USER> (polynomial 0.5)
-1.9495
CL-USER> (polynomial 0.5)
0.8786454
CL-USER> (polynomial 0.5)
0.07474504
CL-USER> (polynomial 0.5)
0.3032537
CL-USER> (polynomial 0.5)
0.23830011
CL-USER>
```

what is going on ? I am using the latest sbcl.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`*` in argument position evaluates to the very last result you had in the REPL. In your code you do `(* -2.274 * (expt x 3))` where `*` is `-1.9495` perhaps after the first run. (You'd get an error when running it the first time if the last result was not a number.)

You can have multiple arguments to both `*` and `+` and all LISPs has polish prefix notation so your function might look better like this:

```
;; f(x) = x^4 - 2.274x^3 + 1.8x^2 - 0.576x + 1.0
(defun polynomial (x)
  (+ (expt x 4) 
     (* -2.274 (expt x 3))
     (* 1.8 x x)
     (* -0.576 x) 
     1.0)) ;; this was originally 0.1

(polynomial 0.5) ; ==>  0.94025004
```

Basically `x + y + z` in infix becomes `(+ x y z)` in prefix.

Comment: `(* -2.274 * (expt x 3))` was my coding mistake and the REPL is assigning values to `*`! now I understand why lisp is an alien technology.

Comment: That's not *all* that strange. Doesn't the python repl do a similar thing with `_`? Also see **, ***, /, //, and ///.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor IMO `*` inside `defun` should produce a warning in a usually verbose SBCL while I wouldn't expect it in other implementations.

Comment: @Sylwester IMHO, there is not only historically a big difference between a RPL ( reverse-polish-notation ) and LISP ( list-processing )

Comment: @user3666197 I haven't mentioned *Reverse polish prefix* (like Forth) at all. Only *infix* (like ALGOL) and *Polish prefix* (like LISP).

Comment: @Sylwester Sure, tried to make a difference between a **LIS**t-**P**rocessing,  where the arity of the operator goes step-wise extended/re-iterated "over" the given list of operands, while the Lukasiewics' *Polish Notation* was arity-strict ( non-extensible ). Anyway, thanks -- you've made me remember the great days with RPL-coding on HP67.